# C# - Add attribute in node when serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, attributes

I have two class :

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class myclass
{
    public string Propertie1 { get; set; }

    public Customer[] Customers { get; set; }
}
```

And on instance + serializer :

```
myclass c = new myclass()
{
    Propertie1 = "value",

    Customers = new Customer[]
    {
        new Customer()
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName1",
            LastName = "LastName1"
        },
        new Customer()
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName2",
            LastName = "LastName2"
        }
    }
};

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myclass));
using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"c:/Temp/customers.xml"))
{
    xs.Serialize(wr, c);
}
```

How to add a attribute in my node for each  ? for exemple

With XmlAttribute maybe ? But I don't know how to use

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

Add another property

```
public class Customer
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int id {get;set;}

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In assinging values to the Customer object:

```
new Customer()
        { 
            id = 1,
            FirstName = "FirstName1",
            LastName = "LastName1"
        },
```

This would give the output for every customer when an id is assigned as follow

```
<myclass>
    <Customer id=1>
      <FirstName>FirstName1</FirstName>
      <LastName>LastName1</LastName>
    </Customer>
    <Customer id=2>
      <FirstName>FirstName2</FirstName>
      <LastName>LastName2</LastName>
    </Customer>
</myclass>
```

I would assume the `Propertie1` in myClass will also have the `[XmlAttribute]`
making it

```
<myclass Propertie1 = "<assinged value>">
```

This **[post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14064/Using-the-XmlSerializer-Attributes)** provides a good overview